# Where is the "Add Dynamic Content" window in my MS-Flow?

Tags: power-automate

Until recently, when building flows, I had the option of clicking on "Add Dynamic Content" to bring up the Dynamic Content/Expressions pop-up.

Now, these options are gone. No link to the pop-up, no pop-up. Just a list of available fields/variables when I click in the step.

Did something change in MS-Flow? I've looked around for settings/preferences but not found any. Am I missing something?

Is it a privileges issue (as in, I should go annoy IT until they restore something)?

Comment: And today...after asking iT to submit to the MS Flow support group ('cause I lack admin privs) mysteriously this functionality is back!

Comment: When updates occur or if your company has a group policy that can hold your privilleges. Make sure you are in the right group and request admin team to assign you in the proper group to continue working

Comment: Thanks Ragavan that makes sense...I got to show someone on IT what the issue was but is not an issue anymore today. Since  i’m the one who is ahead of the curve they were interested but not helpful. Still, got to show off a little 

Comment: Then if you are really interested to explore more on Flow. Try signing up for Office E3 developer account. Where you will get one year free license with full admin privilege. Use this account to showcase your findings and then company will adapt to it.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Try zooming out the page to 75% or less and exit/enter the field again - the dynamic content should appear.

Ridiculous bug.

P.S. Also, if you are using Firefox, there may be additional difficulties with entering the expression - switch to Edge or Chrome.